# I need value of div custom attribute in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parent-child

Please check code below ,

```
<div class="cp_option_color">
  
  <div id="cp-power-manual" class="configure-seats-section">
      <!-- power or manual append -->
   </div>
   <div class="validation-message" style="display:none">Please Select Color</div>
   <div class="cp-color-item-content" data-name="199538" style="display: none;">
      <h2>Black</h2>
      <ul>
         <li data-li="Power Recline">
            <div class="cp-recline" recline="power">
               Power Recline:
               <span class="">
                  <img src="checkmark.png" alt="">Ships in 
                  <lable class="shipmentmsg">6 Days</lable>
               </span>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="cp-color-item-content" data-name="199539" style="display: inline-block;">
      <h2>Brown</h2>
      <ul>
         <li data-li="Power Recline">
            <div class="cp-recline" recline="manual">
               Power Recline:
               <span class="">
                  <img src="checkmark.png" alt="">Ships in 
                  <lable class="shipmentmsg">6 Days</lable>
               </span>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need custom attribute value of 'recline' attribute. If you see, there are same class name of its parent div(cp-color-item-content). But one is display none and another is display block. So, i need custom attribute value of 'display:block' div (i need 'manual' value).

Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, please don't share an image for code. Instead, share the actual code working snippet.  Secondly, for custom attribute user [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), you need to use ``data-*`` before your attribute

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you should be using `data-recline="power"` for custom attributes, you can use

```
.attr("recline")
```

the selector can include `:visible` to exclude the hidden one, giving:

```
 $(".cp-recline:visible").attr("recline")
```

Updated snippet (no change to HTML)

```js
console.log($(".cp-recline:visible").attr("recline"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cp-power-manual" class="configure-seats-section">
      <!-- power or manual append -->
   </div>
   <div class="validation-message" style="display:none">Please Select Color</div>
   <div class="cp-color-item-content" data-name="199538" style="display: none;">
      <h2>Black</h2>
      <ul>
         <li data-li="Power Recline">
            <div class="cp-recline" recline="power">
               Power Recline:
               <span class="">
                  <img src="checkmark.png" alt="">Ships in 
                  <lable class="shipmentmsg">6 Days</lable>
               </span>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="cp-color-item-content" data-name="199539" style="display: inline-block;">
      <h2>Brown</h2>
      <ul>
         <li data-li="Power Recline">
            <div class="cp-recline" recline="manual">
               Power Recline:
               <span class="">
                  <img src="checkmark.png" alt="">Ships in 
                  <lable class="shipmentmsg">6 Days</lable>
               </span>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For defining your own **custom attributes** in HTML, you need to use the prefix as [**data-***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

To get the value of that **custom attributes** you have defined in your HTML through jQuery, you can use the [**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Check the below demo:

```js
let customAttributeValue = $('#this-is-my-id').data('this-is-custom-id');
console.log(customAttributeValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="this-is-my-id" data-this-is-custom-id="manual"></div>
```

Now coming to your code, you can try this:

```js
let reclineValue = $('.cp-recline:visible').data('recline');

console.log("reclineValue is: ",  reclineValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cp_option_color">

  <div id="cp-power-manual" class="configure-seats-section">
    <!-- power or manual append -->
  </div>
  <div class="validation-message" style="display:none">Please Select Color</div>
  <div class="cp-color-item-content" data-name="199538" style="display: none;">
    <h2>Black</h2>
    <ul>
      <li data-li="Power Recline">
        <div class="cp-recline" data-recline="power">
          Power Recline:
          <span class="">
                  <img src="checkmark.png" alt="">Ships in 
                  <lable class="shipmentmsg">6 Days</lable>
               </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cp-color-item-content" data-name="199539" style="display: inline-block;">
    <h2>Brown</h2>
    <ul>
      <li data-li="Power Recline">
        <div class="cp-recline" data-recline="manual">
          Power Recline:
          <span class="">
                  <img src="checkmark.png" alt="">Ships in 
                  <lable class="shipmentmsg">6 Days</lable>
               </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```